# Laravel second test fails

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have one test case with two tests in it like so:

```
class LoginTest extends TestCase {
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testSeeLoginForm() {
        $this->visit('/backend');
    }

    public function testCanLogin() {
        $this->visit('/backend');
    }
}
```

The 2 tests are identical but the first one passes and the second one fails with a 404 (`A request to [http://localhost/backend] failed. Received status code [404].`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code how you are trying to access both methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long journey searching for the problem I finally fixed it.

Apparently, when testing routes, using require_once instead of require breaks the testing.

Comment: yep. require_once is the culprit

Comment: big thumbs up! spent all morning trying to figure this out

Comment: Thanks a lot @frietkot helped a lot.